# javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I want to create a piece of javascript code which doesn't allow the user to submit the form unless at least one event has been checked from the list of checkboxes within a span tag. how would this be done?

Form Name

```
 <form id="bookingForm" name"form1" action="#" method="get">
```

Span class which echos all the events along with a checkbox at the end of the printed event

```
<span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' onclick='checkTerms();' value='{$event['eventID']}' title='{$event['eventPrice']}' /></span>
```

Submit button code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Make booking" id="sub1" disabled=disable />
```

Comment: Write a method which is called you click submit. In that iterate over all the checkboxes and check if any one of them is checked or not.

Comment: There's plenty of resources on **form validation**. You'll want to basically attach an event to the form when it's submitted to do your checks, and either continue with form submission or reject based on that validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkCheckboxes() {
    if (document.querySelector('input[name="event\\[\\]"]:checked') == null) {
        document.getElementById('sub1').disabled = 'disabled';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('sub1').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
}
```

Change the `onclick` attribute of the checkboxes to:

```
onclick="checkCheckboxes(); checkTerms();"
```